# Android - how to add an item click method to an ArrayAdapter

Tags: android, android-arrayadapter

I have a simple ArrayAdapter. I want to set up a listener for every row click of my list such that a new Activity opens. How would I do that? My ArrayAdapter code -

```
public class CountryListAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<String> {
private final Activity context;
private final ArrayList<String> names;

public CountryListAdapter(Activity context, ArrayList<String> names) {
    super(context, R.layout.rowlayout, names);
    this.context = context;
    this.names = names;
}

@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = context.getLayoutInflater();
    View rowView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.rowlayout, null, true);
    TextView textView = (TextView) rowView.findViewById(R.id.label);
    textView.setText(names.get(position));
    return rowView;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Assuming you are using a `ListActivity` implementing `OnItemClickListener`
you could use this code:

```
ArrayAdapter<Object> ad = new ArrayAdapter<Object>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_checked, items);
        setListAdapter(ad);
        ListView list = getListView();
        list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
        //list.setItemChecked(0, true);
        list.setOnItemClickListener(this);
```

**EDIT:**
Otherwise, if you don't extend ListActivity, have a listview in your layout and replace `ListView list = getListView()` with something like `ListView list = findViewById(R.id.listView)`. Replace `list.setOnItemClickListener(this)` with

```
list.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {

            }
        });
```

Comment: Is there any way to bind the onClick logic to the ArrayAdapter(or any other adapter)? I have one adapter, but multple ListViews, that are filled with it, and it would be nicer to bind it to the Adapter itself?

Answer (score 4):

Simply implement AdapterView.OnItemClickListener.

```
@Override
public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int pos, long l) {
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ProductActivity.class);
    i.putExtra("item_id", manager.getItemIdAtIndex(pos));
    startActivity(i);
}
```

Then just set the class with that method as the onItemClickListener in your adaptor.

Answer (score -1):

Once you have set your adapter using:

```
mListView.setAdapter(myCountryListAdapter);
```

Then you can setup a click listener for the listview:

```
mListView.setOnParentClickListener(new  OnClickListener() {         
    public void onClick(View view,) {
            ///do what you want the click to do
    }       
    });
```