# How can I open the file in arrayadapter list after clicking?

Tags: android, listview, android-arrayadapter, android-adapterview

I'm listing PDF files in folder. But I want them to be named as filename, instead of sdcard/mypath/files Also, I want to open them whenever I click them via PDF viewer. My code:

```
public class activity1 extends ListActivity {

private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    File root = new File("sdcard/mypath");
    ListDir(root);
}

void ListDir(File f) {
    File[] files = f.listFiles();
    fileList.clear();
    for (File file : files) {
        fileList.add(file.getPath());
    }
    ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
    setListAdapter(directoryList);
}}
```

Comment: did u try to use ``onclick`` method?

Comment: Thanks Donald! No. I haven't thinking of using setOnItemClickListener. Where should I use it? Also, what about the names?

Comment: you can try to ``setOnItemClickListener`` to your ``directoryList ``

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8615417/how-can-i-set-onclicklistener-on-arrayadapter

Comment: I'm not able to use directoryList.setOnItemClickListener

Comment: your ``listView``?

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126175/android-how-to-add-an-item-click-method-to-an-arrayadapter

Comment: Not list view using array adapter. Edited question. Will try that Donald Wu.

Comment: I'm not able to perform operations on file.It says we need to declare it as final. But after declaring it as final, its remaining static. Whats the solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
   public class activity1 extends ListActivity {
   ListView lv;
   private List<String> fileList = new ArrayList<String>();

  @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    File root = new File("sdcard/mypath");
      lv = getListView();
        ListDir(root);
       }

     void ListDir(File f) {
      File[] files = f.listFiles();
   fileList.clear();
for (File file : files) {
    fileList.add(file.getName());
}
ArrayAdapter<String> directoryList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, fileList);
setListAdapter(directoryList);
    lv.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int i, long l) {
            viewPdf(fileList.get(i));
        }
    });
}

 }}
```

and open the file in pdf default pdf viewer

```
     private void viewPdf(String file) {

        File pdfFile = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() +    "/" + "mypath"+ "/" + file);
        Uri path = Uri.fromFile(pdfFile);

       // Setting the intent for pdf reader
    Intent pdfIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    pdfIntent.setDataAndType(path, "application/pdf");
    pdfIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);


        startActivity(pdfIntent);
   }
```

Use the above code..
Hope it helps!

Comment: thank you! But how can I open those files? And How can I name them appropriately instead of their file paths.

Comment: while sending names to adapter just sent the file names alone instead of the file paths by

Comment: file.getName();

Comment: now see the updated answer by this u can open the pdf files... Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

Below  code will help to open the file with as these type. check this answer:

```
 public static Intent getOpenFileIntent(Context ctx, String path) {

    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
    try {
        File file = new File(path);
        Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        String extension = MimeTypeMap.getFileExtensionFromUrl(path);
        if (extension != null) {
            String type = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getMimeTypeFromExtension(extension);
            boolean status = canDisplay(ctx, type);
            if (type == null || !status) {
                type = "*/*";
            }
            if (!status) {
                Toast.makeText(ctx, "Cannot find appropriate Application", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
            intent.setDataAndType(uri, type);
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AppLog.exception(e);
    }
    return intent;
}
```

and below code will check that the particular actionview app is present or not

```
   static boolean canDisplay(Context context, String mimeType) {
    try {
        PackageManager packageManager = context.getPackageManager();
        Intent testIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
        testIntent.setType(mimeType);
        return packageManager.queryIntentActivities(testIntent, PackageManager.MATCH_DEFAULT_ONLY).size() > 0;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        AppLog.exception(e);
    }
    return false;
}
```

if the file type can openable, it will show the file with appropriate application or list the application can open the file.

**UPDATE**

**Before send the file to this function make sure , that the particular file is present and readable.**