# How to scroll my layout to particular textview in android?

Tags: java, android

In my android app I want to scroll my layout upto one particular textview using Java in Android Studio. But here I don't know how to give my textview in `.scrollTo()` . Anybody can help me?

Comment: Simply set the focus on that View.

Comment: @Fantômas Thanks buddy... But I have another doubt. If suppose I want to get the ID of a textView using its text? Could you help me?

Comment: if your text is inside scrollView then just try scrollView.scrollTo(0, (int)textView.getY()) or  scrollView. smoothScrollTo(0, (int)textView.getY())

Comment: Hi @AnkitAman... In your code `textView` means my text right?

Comment: yes, scrollView.scrollTo(0, (int)textView.getY())

Comment: Ok @AnkitAman.. See here upto I have tried... `String mytext = "Category 1"; scrollView.scrollTo(0, (int)mytext.getY());`. But here I got error in `getY()`

Comment: you are writing in Kotlin ? then try this scrollView.smoothScrollTo(0, mytext.y.toInt()

Comment: Using Java only @AnkitAman buddy...

Comment: can you ping the error message what you are getting

Comment: `Cannot resolve method 'getY()'` @AnkitAman

Comment: @AnkitAman buddy.. Did you got any solution?

Comment: Is your mytext is String or TextView

Comment: @AnkitAman TextView only.. But that is dynamic one so I don't know the ID

Comment: You would have to cycle through your Views and stop when you find the one with the matching text.

Comment: @Fantômas Is there any examples?

Comment: I'm sure there is, if you search a bit.

Comment: @RanjithKumar Best is create a recycler view or array adapter and put each text as item of it. to scroll to position us recyclerView..getLayoutManager().scrollToPosition(youPositionInTheAdapter). Second approach is maintain a instance of all textViews in an array which you are adding in your layout and pass particular textview instance to scroll view to scroll. And there are many ways this can be done.

Comment: Thanks buddy @AnkitAman ... Is there any link for that?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8126175/android-how-to-add-an-item-click-method-to-an-arrayadapter

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
View v = findViewById(R.id.someId);  
v.getParent().requestChildFocus(targetView,targetView);
```